# Read txt data in C++, expand into a row or column and sort

Tags: c++

I am a newcomer to C++. need to write a piece of code in C++, read the txt data, expand into one dimension (one row or one column) and sort in descending order. Finally I want to specify a percentage range to average. I found some code snippets on the web and debugged it like this, but in the sorting phase I can't get the results I want, all the data will be turned into -858993460. Hope someone can help me.
[txtfile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eljq3.png)

```
    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include <vector>
    #include<iostream>
    #include<algorithm>
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<fstream>
    #include<typeinfo>
    using namespace std;

    int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
    {
        int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
        int t = 0, f = 0;
        int data[20];

        ifstream infile;
        infile.open("C:\\Users\n\Desktop\1111.txt");
        for ( i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            for ( j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            {
                infile >> data[k++];
            }
        }   
        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            {
                if (data[i] > data[j]) //Sort from big to small
                {
//Exchange the values of both
                    t = data[i];
                    data[i] = data[j];
                    data[j] = t;
                }

            }
        }
        for (int f = 0; f < 20; f++)
        {
            cout << data[f];
            cout << '\n';
        }
        system("PAUSE");
    }
```

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZTaw.png)

Comment: Just create a `std::vector<type>` and read your data and convert to the desired type and add it to your vector. Then use [std::sort](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) to sort it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape your

> \

If you change your

`infile.open("C:\\Users\n\Desktop\1111.txt");`

to

`infile.open("C:\\Users\\n\\Desktop\\1111.txt");` it should work properly.

**EDIT:** I just reproduced your file and I can read all your inputs. I think there is still a problem with the opening process of your file.

Another problem: You read in 20 values into an array. Therefore you dont need 2 nested for loop. One loop which counts to 20 is enough to do that task. This is a main reason why your sorting algorithm wont work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I just added the missing "\" and it still hasn't changed.

Comment: You might add the content of the file, for me its working.

Comment: Did you added all missing "\"?

Answer (score 0):

Some strange code but your main error is not checking that the file open has succeeded. The garbage values you are getting strongly suggests that the file open has failed.

Files can fail to open for lots of reasons (include the one that cKai mentioned above). Add the following to your code to check if the file has opened.

```
ifstream infile;
infile.open("C:\\Users\\n\\Desktop\\1111.txt");
if (!infile.is_open())
{
    cerr << "file open failed, quitting\n";
    system("PAUSE");
    return 1;
}
```

**EDIT**

OK so the above didn't prove anything, now maybe try this. Change

```
            infile >> data[k++];
```

to this

```
            if (!(infile >> data[k++]))
            {
                cerr << "read failed, quitting\n";
                system("PAUSE");
                return 1;
            }
```

and see if that produces any error messages.

Comment: thank you for your answer.I added the line you said to detect if the file was successfully opened. The result of the operation is unchanged, indicating that the file is successfully opened, right?

Comment: Yes the file opened. The only other thing I can think of is some kind of encoding issue in your file. Do you know how your file is encoded?

Comment: I mean I notice that your computer is Japanese. If you have some kind of encoding on your file that C++ is not expecting it could explain the problem.

Comment: Probably the next thing to check is that each read has succeeded. See the edit above.

Comment: I have solved this problem. The problem is that the program I have been debugging is not the one I am executing. Thank you very much.

Comment: @BK201 Yeah, it does happen